# Showing that $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ is bounded

Tags: probability-theory

I have an exercise where I have to show that the probability of the intersection of two sets is bounded. I have done it but I would like to get some feedback on whether I have approached it the right way, and also if my reasoning is water-tight.

The questions is: Let $A$ and $B$ be two events with probabilities $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ respectively. Show that $\frac{1}{12} \leq \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \leq \frac{1}{3}$.

What I did was to use the following formula:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \\
1 = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{3} - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \\
\frac{1}{12} = \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)
\end{eqnarray}

Is this sufficient to show that the intersection is bounded as stated in the question? Please just offer hints and pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Use $0\leq \mathbb{P}(A\cup B)\leq 1$

Comment: I.K. : why do you assume $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B)=1$?

Comment: @anaconda, that's actually the second part of question: to show the pounds for A union B.

Comment: @ClementC., I picked 1 first as that is the max value that A union B could have and because I want to find the limits, I plugged in this extreme value first.

Comment: You cannot really plug an equality here, as you can't assume anything about these particular arbitrary $A,B$. First, use inequalities to prove bounds on the range the value can take; then only, pick *specific* examples of sets $A,B$ satisfying the assumptions for which the extremal values of your range are reached, in order to prove your bounds cannot be improved.

Comment: Yes I realised that once I saw your solution. I wasn't really sure how to approach this type of question but it's clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Hint:**
  One bound (the lower bound) comes from the formula you used, and the fact that $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) \leq 1$. The upper bound comes from the fact that if $E \subseteq F$, then $\mathbb{P}E \leq \mathbb{P}F$.
- **More details** *(full solution)*

One bound:
$$1 \geq \mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{3} - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) =  \frac{13}{12} - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)  $$
so, reorganizing,
$$ \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \geq \frac{13}{12} - 1 = \frac{1}{12}.$$

For the second:  $A\cap B\subseteq B$, so
$$ \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \leq \mathbb{P}B = \frac{1}{3}.$$

- **Edit:** Following Did's comment — optimality of the bounds.

  - Take $B\subseteq A$, so that $A \cap B=B$. Then $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P} B = \frac{1}{3}$.
  - Take $B\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\bar{A}+C$, where $\bar{A}$ is the complement of $A$ (having probability measure $\mathbb{P}\bar{A}=\frac{1}{4}$) and $C\subseteq A$, thus with probability measure $$\mathbb{P} C= \mathbb{P} B - \mathbb{P}\bar{A} = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}.$$
    You get $A \cap B=C$, so that $\mathbb{P} A\cap B = \frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: And these bounds are optimal because ... on the one hand and ... on the other hand.

Comment: @Did: updated accordingly.